# Are algebraic symplectic manifolds locally exact?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic

my guess is "no", even in the etale topology.

Are there interesting examples of algebraic symplectic manifolds which are locally exact in Zariski or etale topology?  What about Hilbert schemes of K3 surfaces, for example?

A precise mathematical statement would be: Let $X$ be an algebraic symplectic manifold with symplectic form $\omega$, then there exists an etale cover $U\to X$, and an algebraic 1-form $\alpha$ on $U$, such that $d\alpha=\omega|_U$.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but [smooth morphisms are étale locally like affine spaces](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/054L), and in char 0, affine spaces have trivial higher algebraic de Rham cohomology, so closed forms are exact?

Comment: I think the symplectic form $(dx/x) \wedge (dy/y)$ on $\mathbb C^\times \times \mathbb C^\times$ is not etale locally exact.

Comment: @Z.M The result you quoted says that a point in a smooth variety $X$ has a (Zariski) open neighborhood $U$ with an etale map $\pi$ onto an open subset of affine space. In the case of $\mathbb C^\times$ you can just take $U=X=\mathbb C^\times$ and $\pi$ to be the inclusion into $\mathbb A^1$; but this result doesn't help trivialize the form $dx/x$.